# Loop formatting for query strings

Tags: python, curl, lambda, formatting, query-string

I have a query string for a url that specifies days `[now-%dd TO now-%dd]` and I want to write a function to have this query updated with days just like with a for loop:
`now-1d TO now-2d
 now-2d TO now-3d
 now-3d TO now-4d`

Thus a request will be sent properly.

The thing I have for now is

`>>> '[now-{}d TO now-{}d]'.format([x + 1 for x in range(5)], [x for x in range(5)])
'[now-[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]d TO now-[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]d]'`

Is there a way to have an expected result in one liner? Probably a lambda? 
I'm kinda stuck with this

Comment: What is the desired output format? a list of those strings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get all list of all those strings's:

```
[f'now-{x} TO now-{x+1}' for x in range(1,6)]
```

Outputs:

```
['now-1 TO now-2', 'now-2 TO now-3', 'now-3 TO now-4', 'now-4 TO now-5', 'now-5 TO now-6']
```

I gave the range function a starting value (1) as that is a little easier to read.